# how to store JSON into POJO using Jackson

Tags: json, rest

I am developing a module where i am using rest service to get data. i am not getting how to store JSON using Jackson and store it which has Queryparam also. Any help is really appreciated as I am new to this.I am trying to do server side filtering in extjs infinte grid which is sending the below request to rest service.

When the page load first time, it sends:

```
http://myhost/mycontext/rest/populateGrid?_dc=9999999999999&page=1&start=0&limit=500
```

When you select filter on name and place, it sends:

```
http://myhost/mycontext/rest/populateGrid?_dc=9999999999999&filter=[{"type":"string","value":"Tom","field":"name"},{"type":"string","value":"London","field":"Location"}]&page=1&start=0&limit=500
```

I am trying to save this in POJO and then sending this to database to retrieve data. For this on rest side I have written something like this:

```
@Provider
@Path("/rest")
public interface restAccessPoint {
@GET
@Path("/populateGrid")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getallGridData(FilterJsonToJava filterparam,@QueryParam("page") String page,@QueryParam("start") String start,@QueryParam("limit") String limit);
}

public class FilterJsonToJava {
@JsonProperty(value ="filter")
private List<Filter> data;
.. getter and setter below
}

public class Filter {
@JsonProperty("type")
private String type;
@JsonProperty("value")
private String value;
@JsonProperty("field")
private String field;
...getter and setters below
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes: WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public abstract javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.xx.xx.xx.xxxxx (com.xx.xx.xx.xx.json.FilterJsonToJava ,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.  

com.xx.xx.xx.xx.json.FilterJsonToJava, and Java type class com.xx.xx.xx.FilterJsonToJava, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found  

[11/6/13 17:46:54:065] 0000001c ContainerRequ E   The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:

application/octet-stream  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider */* -> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to do it this way:

```
Response getallGridData(@QueryParam("filter") String filterparam, ...) { 

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Filter yourObject = mapper.readValue(filterparam, Filter.class);

}
```

This is the way, because your payload is in the query parameter. The object injected as it is with POST requests when there is a payload.